# Unable to install pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Collecting pygame
Using cached pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y044p4mq\pygame\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y044p4mq\pygame\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-m8a9tj8v'
cwd: C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y044p4mq\pygame
Complete output (17 lines):

```
WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
Using WINDOWS configuration...


Download prebuilts to "prebuilt_downloads" and copy to "./prebuilt-x64"? [Y/n]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y044p4mq\pygame\setup.py", line 194, in <module>
    buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y044p4mq\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 210, in main
    deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y044p4mq\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 576, in main
    and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-y044p4mq\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 302, in ask
    reply = raw_input(
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score -1):

To install `pygame`:

- On Windows: `pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev14`
- On Mac OS and Linux: `pip3 install pygame==2.0.0.dev14`

Comment: The command worked, Thanks!

Comment: But I am unable to add Pygame in Pycharm IDE

Comment: @ParthZile Create a new project with your base interpreter in PyCharm. To see how to do that check https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-empty-project.html